# JPA findAll Pageable Request Total Count Group By Column

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, pageable

I have a code like below:

```
Pageable pageableRequest = PageRequest.of(page, limit, Sort.by(sortBy));
Page<User> userList= null;
userList = this.user.findAll(pageableRequest)
```

from here I get all the data and total is shown. However, I want to group the total by status. How can I achieve that? Now total is 26 and I have 3 status inactive, active and vip.

Comment: `I want to group the total by status` by count, data? have you tried writing query?

Comment: I have tried something like below but it is only returning 3 values but I am not getting all user only one from each group

@Query("SELECT u FROM User u GROUP BY status")
Page<User> findAll();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have all users grouped by status you can do something like below.

Ask for all users and than group it in java

```
List<User> userList = this.user.findAll();
Map<Status, List<User>> mapResult = userList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getStatus));
```

Comment: I need to return as Page<User>. How can I accomplish this with the above?

Comment: How it should looked like with `Page<User>`. For example: with 25 users and page size 10? @CloudSeph

Comment: You can use `Page<User>` and do this `this.user.findAll(pageableRequest).stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getStatus));` but it only map for subList not all users @CloudSeph

Comment: @Iczapski I can't do that. I will get incompatible types.

Comment: @CloudSeph Where is 'incompatible types'?

Comment: The above Page <User> user = this.user.findAll(pageableRequest).stream() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getStatus));

Comment: this part is the one giving me the error. Incompatible types. Required <Page> User but collect was inferred to R: no instance of type variable .K, T  exist so that Map<K, List<T>> conforms to Page <User>